# cのビット演算で特定のビットを指定したビットに置き換える関数を作りたい

Tags: c

c言語で、ある特定の1バイトを指定した1バイトに変える関数を作成したいです。

```
int okikae(0x12345678, 0xFF, 2) // 0x12FF5678 が戻り値
int okikae(0x12345678, 0xFF, 0) // 0x123456FF が戻り値
```

といった具合で、演算子を ~!|&^+>><<だけ使い、かつif文やwhile文、変数宣言などをせずに作りたいのですがどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 「指定したビット」は1バイト固定ですか？ そうでないとすると `0xFF` と `0x00FF` が区別できず、上位ビットを 0 にするかどうかを決められないと思います。

Comment: 第3引数`n`の意味は「下位ビット(LSB)側から`n`*8 〜 (`n`+1)*8-1ビット目を対象とする」でしょうかね？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 指定するビットは1byte固定です

Comment: @yohjp はい、nの対象はその通りです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ビットマスクを使って実装してみました。 ([下のコードの Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mrkIaweCg6zLQrJE))

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t okikae(uint32_t data, uint8_t byte, uint8_t shift) {
  // ここで shift が3以下であることを確認したほうが良いでしょう
  uint32_t mask = ~((uint32_t)0xFF << (shift * 8));
  uint32_t answer = (data & mask) | ((uint32_t)byte << (shift * 8));
  printf("        data = 0x%08x\n", data);
  printf("        byte = 0x%08x\n", byte);
  printf("        mask = 0x%08x\n", mask);
  printf(" masked data = 0x%08x\n", data & mask);
  printf("shifted byte = 0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)byte << (shift * 8));
  printf("      return = 0x%08x\n\n", answer);
  return answer;
}

int main() {
  okikae(0x12345678, 0xFF, 0);
  okikae(0x12345678, 0xFF, 1);
  okikae(0x12345678, 0xFF, 2);
  okikae(0x12345678, 0xFF, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

```
        data = 0x12345678
        byte = 0x000000ff
        mask = 0xffffff00
 masked data = 0x12345600
shifted byte = 0x000000ff
      return = 0x123456ff

        data = 0x12345678
        byte = 0x000000ff
        mask = 0xffff00ff
 masked data = 0x12340078
shifted byte = 0x0000ff00
      return = 0x1234ff78

        data = 0x12345678
        byte = 0x000000ff
        mask = 0xff00ffff
 masked data = 0x12005678
shifted byte = 0x00ff0000
      return = 0x12ff5678

        data = 0x12345678
        byte = 0x000000ff
        mask = 0x00ffffff
 masked data = 0x00345678
shifted byte = 0xff000000
      return = 0xff345678
```

変更されるべき部分をマスクで 0 にリセットし、その後指定した1バイトを bitwise-or で挿入しています。

※ 説明のために変数宣言をしていますが、1行にまとめることができます。

Comment: 有難うございます!  ちなみに↑のコードを考える際の思考プロセスがどう辿ったのか聞いても良いでしょうか？

Comment: うーん、そうですね、大体「`byte` を目的の場所までシフトして置き換えれば良い」→「置き換えるときに `byte` 以外のビットが 0 であることを処理しないといけない」→「ビットマスクを使って目的の場所をリセットしてから置き換えることにすれば考えなくてよい」、みたいな感じでしょうか……。マスクする手法自体は元から知っていたので、そこは自分でイチから思いついた訳ではないです。